# How do I add a view to the top of an app in iOS 13/14

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiwindow

I'm trying to add a view to my app that is persistent across flows and sits above all other views. In previous versions of iOS i've been able to simply add a subview to the `UIWindow` that sat atop my application however it would appear that as of iOS 13 this is no longer possible.

I've tried the following, but to no success:
`UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })?.addSubview(someView)`

Debugging a bit further, it appears that my app does not have a window at all present on its view hierarchy. I know this because when putting a breakpoint on the follow forEach statement, I never get a breakpoint to execute.

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.forEach { (window) in
    window.addSubview(myView)
}
```

Any advice on how to achieve this, on all iOS versions 11 through 14 would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you try this? `let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
window.addSubview(myView)`

Comment: @emrcftci yes, that method is deprecated though as of iOS 13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a second `UIWindow`, assign the `rootViewController` and make it visible.

The code bellow is for SwiftUI, but you can do the same with UIKit, just create a window and set `window.isHidden = false`.

```swift
let secondWindow = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
secondWindow.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 40, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 100)
let someView = Text("I am on top of everything")
secondWindow.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: someView)
secondWindow.isHidden = false
```

Depending on how many windows you have. You might need to change the `windowLevel` of your second window.
You can check if the window is displayed using `Debug View Hierarchy` from Xcode.

This is a UIKit example without SceneDelegate. If you have scene delegate you have to pass the window scene to the UIWindow init.
Don't forget to retain the second window.

```swift
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    private enum Constants {
        static let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    }

    var window: UIWindow?
    var secondWindow: UIWindow?

    // MARK: - UIApplicationDelegate

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

        let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window = window
        let viewController = UIViewController()
        viewController.view.backgroundColor = .red

        window.rootViewController = viewController
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()

        let secondWindow = UIWindow()
        secondWindow.frame = CGRect(
            x: 0,
            y: 40,
            width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width,
            height: 100
        )

        let secondController = UIViewController()
        secondController.view.backgroundColor = .blue
        secondWindow.rootViewController = secondController
        secondWindow.isHidden = false
        self.secondWindow = secondWindow

        return true
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. The following code simply renders nothing on top of my app.

```var window = UIWindow()
        window.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        window.rootViewController = UIViewController()
        window.addSubview(GridOverlayView())
        window.isHidden = false
```

Comment: I am not sure what are you doing wrong, but I tested with both SceneDelegate and without and it works.

Comment: So the problem with this implementation is that it does not account for multiple windows. I will accept this and mark it as solved, however for an implementation that does solve this across all windows, you need to setup notifications and observe when new windows became available. See https://github.com/bstillitano/Scyther